# Array key as string and number

Tags: php, arrays

How to make arrays in which the key is number and string.

```
<?php
$array = array
(
    'test' => 'thing',
    'blah' => 'things'
);

echo $array[0]; // thing
echo $array[1]; // things

echo $array['test']; // thing
echo $array['blah']; // things
?>
```

Comment: your question is not clear, what exactly do you want/mean?

Comment: That won't work reliably. The order of the items in an assoziative array is not depending on the order in which they are entered. The first element in the array might as well be `blah` instead of `test`.

Comment: @dbemerlin: Do you have a reference supporting your comment? I've always thought associative arrays were ordered according to the order of insertion, but I can't find anything in the manual that says one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

but why would you need that? can you extend your example?

Comment: I need the original keys, trying to assign a value to a key which is a string and I have only the number

Answer (score 2):

You could use array_keys to generate a lookup array:

```
<?php
$array = array
(
    'test' => 'thing',
    'blah' => 'things'
);
$lookup = array_keys ($array);
// $lookup holds (0=>'test',1=>'blah)

echo $array[$lookup[0]]; // thing
echo $array[$lookup[1]]; // things

echo $array['test']; // thing
echo $array['blah']; // things
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own class that "implements  ArrayAccess"

For such class you can manually handle such behaviour

**UPD**: implemented just for fun

```
class MyArray implements ArrayAccess
{
    private $data;
    private $keys;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->keys = array_keys($data);
    }

    public function offsetGet($key)
    {
        if (is_int($key))
        {
            return $this->data[$this->keys[$key]];
        }

        return $this->data[$key];
    }

    public function offsetSet($key, $value)
    {
        throw new Exception('Not implemented');
    }

    public function offsetExists($key)
    {
        throw new Exception('Not implemented');
    }

    public function offsetUnset($key)
    {
        throw new Exception('Not implemented');
    }
}

$array = new MyArray(array(
    'test' => 'thing',
    'blah' => 'things'
));

var_dump($array[0]);
var_dump($array[1]);
var_dump($array['test']);
var_dump($array['blah']);
```